# partial order on sets and union

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

Starting with and equivalence relation $\sim$ on sets, I have defined a partial order using union in a familiar way: $A \sqsubset B$ iff $A\cup B\sim B$.

My question: what property of $\sim$ is needed to make $A \sim B$ imply that $A \sqsubset B$?

Presently I use that "my" $\sim$ is "closed under union", as in: $A\sim B$ and  $A'\sim B'$ imply  $A\cup B \sim A'\cup B'$. But I suspect there might be some general result in order theory.

Comment: the iff is understood as the iff in a definition. Moreover, what mean $A\sqsubset B$, is it the normal inclusion ?

Comment: @Surb No, it is not the usual subset relation. I start with an abstract $\sim$ and from that derive the new order relation $\sqsubset$.

Comment: The relation doesn't seem to be anti-symmetric: from $A\cup B \sim A$ and $A \cup B \sim B$ it doesn't follow that $A=B$, but rather that $A \sim B$. Maybe you're trying to define the relation on the quotient set?

Comment: @amrsa You are right. In the end it will be a partial order on the quotient set, as you observe. But I was wondering, what "general" properties of $\sim$ do I need to conclude that $\sim$ implies $\sqsubset$? (For my specific application I can prove this, but I am curious whether I am overlooking some obvious facts from order theory.)

Comment: @HendrikJan It has to have some kind of compatibility with the order (something we would call a congruence relation, if this was an algebra). For example, if $A\sim B$ but $A$ and $B$ are not related with $A\cup B$, then it doesn't fulfill your requirement that $A\sim B$ implies $A \sqsubset B$.

Comment: This is transitive?

Comment: @amrsa Thanks! Your last hint actually gave a push to solve my problem. To be precise: $A\sim B$ implies $A\cup C \sim B\cup C$. That "congruence" implies that $\sqsubset$ is anti-symmetric (on the quotient) and transitive.